# How can I feedback on the "short survey" prompt?

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting, short-survey

I just got this prompt:

[image]

I clicked on "Take a short survey", which took me to:

[image]

The question is asking me to evaluate the answers, but the prompt appears before the answers, so how can I evaluate them?

Is there anywhere I can provide this feedback? There was no link on the prompt or subsequent page.

Comment: *"the prompt appears before the answers, so how can I evaluate them?"* Scroll down and look at them?

Comment: Nothing is forcing you to click on the prompt instead of viewing the answers, and I doubt anything is preventing you from going back to the question and viewing the answers.

Comment: @RyanM The two screenshots are on different pages, once I'm on the second page I cannot scroll down. I'm sensing defensiveness here, Stackoverflow has a problem with out of date answers and I want to help it improve, that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: To be clear, I don't work for Stack Overflow, and I'm a frequent critic of their design choices in general.  However, it seems like in this case, it's clear enough what the survey will be about that one could know that they'd need to read through the answers to fill it out.  That said, perhaps the phrasing could be improved: "Once you've had a chance to read through the answers..."

Comment: @RyanM "Are the answers below sorted in a way that puts the best answer at or near the top?". I don't understand how this couldn't be perceived as an issue.

Comment: What is the issue with that statement? It's asking you to take a survey to comment on if the answers below that element are in a good order. To comment on the answers below it is reasonable to expect that the user would scroll down and read the answers. You also show that there is no back button, but you're not showing your tabs, so I assume it opened a new tab since I highly doubt the survey found an exploit in your browser to clobber the `window.history` stack.

Comment: @vandench I didn't say there was an issue with  the correctness of the statement, there is an issue with the flow of the UX. How can I feedback on answers I haven't seen yet? Stackoverflow information flows from top to bottom.

Comment: (+1). yep-yep, I had exactly the same Feeling like @OP..., and only from seeing this Thread, I thought "**Oh yeah, let's have a Look at this Survey, I saw a Link "some time earlier", "*stupidly*" placed before I had any Chance to read any of the Answers, I had already forgotten about it, let's give it a 2nd chance...**", (because I first scrolled down to read the Content I wanted..., and apparently already forgot about that "_stupid_" Survey Link "above"...), but I can't find any open Tab with that Survey on it...

Comment: @vandench You are correct: when you click on the survey link it opens in a new tab/window. I was able to test this by going to [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), which is old and has a ton of answers and, sure enough, there was a survey link for feedback on trending sort.

Comment: @BSMP Maybe it was a bug, but when I was shown the prompt it did not open in a new tab

Comment: A bug or they've changed how the link works? If you can find another survey link you can see if it happens again.

Comment: Thanks to @BSMP's Link, here is the Answer I gave to the Survey: "*The Invite to the Survey is stupidly placed before I had any chance to read any of the Answers, how should I know...!? //
Nice to open the Survey in a 2nd Tab but should mention that. //
Upon clicking on the Link for the Survey, the Box automatically disappears, which I don't like either... (... and doesn't come back upon refreshing the Qt/Page...)*"

Comment: ... While I would have been very-very inclined to answer the Survey (in a *positively constructive way*), if the Box had mentioned stg like "The Survey will open in a 2nd Tab, you can read the Content of this Page and switch later to the 'Survey' Tab when you've finished reading the Content you were looking for on this current Page... Thanks for your Feedback..." (And I guess I would also have paid attention to *all* Answers, not only the one or few ones that "interested" me, to be able to "rate" the 'Trending Sort'...)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it makes sense to put this survey-invite on top

Why do I think so?

- When you notice that some cheese is moving, you sometimes would like to provide feedback, and the survey is a convenient way to do it. You’ll then check answers and will remember you can leave feedback
- Maybe one hasn’t noticed the change yet, but thanks to survey making accent on it, they will notice and evaluate it
- One does not simply check all the answers to the bottom, so placing it, for example, on the bottom is a hardly good option
- Making it a popup which appears at some point on scrolling is also not a good idea. I personally do think so, I don’t love when something tries to attract my attention in this way.

Is there any other option?

Comment: Another option would be to use the right hand column for it, and have it fixed so it scrolls with the user.

Comment: @IanNewson That wouldn’t work on mobile browsers though, would it? And messing with the layout of the question page would take an awful lot of convincing, especially for something temporary like a survey.

Comment: @BSMP That's true, but on mobile they already flow the right hand column to beneath the main content anyway, which I think is where this button should be an in the first place.

Answer (score -11):

**No**, the *short survey* isn't asking you to evaluate any of the answers.

Rather the survey is based on sorting algorithm recently implemented. The sole aim of the survey is to conduct an opinion poll if the algorithm is putting the best effective answer on the top of the other answers and if you agree to the outcome of the algorithm.

Comment: How could one possibly do this without evaluating the answers to see which one is the best?

Comment: @RyanM The options are permutation and combination of _Highest Score_, _Date Modified_, _Date Created_ and _Acceptance_ by the OP and of coarse _Trending(recent votes count more)_

Comment: That has nothing to do with what the survey is asking.  It's asking if the answers are currently sorted in a way that puts the best answer at or near the top.  That has nothing to do with how the other options would have sorted it differently.

Comment: Yes, in short the survey validates if the _Trending(recent votes count more)_ option is flawless.

Comment: And again: how is one supposed to determine that _without looking at the answers_ to evaluate which one is actually best, and then checking if it's at or near the top?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but my guess would be answerers with a trending answer on a specific question while revisiting the specific question may find the survey link atleast for once.

Comment: It doesn't show to just answerers, my screenshots are from a question I have never seen before. I desperately want to help stackoverflow improve the current situation of showing decade old answers.